# During rest, jax-rs replace some symbol whit question marks. why and where this happen?

Tags: rest, vue.js, filter, utf-8, jax-rs

GoodEvening.
I'm struggling whit a little trivial problem who, eventually, lead to a bigger question.

I have a front app (vue framework, javascript) who send to me a body whit a json inside, inside this json they should sent me some "coins" information, such as symbol.
Now we just notice every time the backend app ( we do not use any "framework", just the javax.ws.rs library) sent some symbols, it will turn into a ???, but not whit all the symbols(dollar work fine).
We just resolve this behaviour, forcing our front to send us the correct code \u20AC, but i rly want to know where javax.ws.rs perform the conversion from bytestream into string (and then into pojo): we perform a filter on container request filters, but i suppose the conversion was already been done by the libraries.
We check and the backend using UTF-8

can't rly find anything online since lot of this problem would be resolved by other framework (like spring) or by other mean.

This is log from backend app

```
==========================================
{"Accept":["*/*"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip"],"Authorization":
["Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi7sFGdnidgyv299.eyJzdWIiOiJPcmdzIiwiaWRTaXRlIjoyNSwiaXNzIgdb/&dsbujdbvjkBHgh23MTYyMzMzMjQ2MSwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiJ9.
CgEDhHQQdfKbhdezsQDxQXPcXzI_yxSfuS_cGMBA"],"Cache-Control":["no-cache"],"CDN-Loop":["cloudflare"],"CF-Connecting-IP":["99.26.27.204"],
"CF-IPCountry":["IT"],"CF-RAY":["65d19be2ab4efc7d-FCO"],"cf-request-id":["0a96yrtutrtiitti000001"],"CF-Visitor":["{\"scheme\":\"https\"}"],
"Connection":["close"],"Content-Length":["333"],"Content-Type":["application/json; charset\u003dutf-16"],"Host":["wildfly:3331"],
"Postman-Token":["945fbey-42a0-4086-abc3-963eklbc5c4"],"User-Agent":["PostmanRuntime/7.21.1"],
"X-Forwarded-For":["9.26.27.204, 177.88.118.109","20.0.0.3"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["https"],
"X-Real-IP":["177.88.118.109"],"X-Request-Timestamp":["1623316319509"]}
 09:35:19,510 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ==========================================
 09:35:19,511 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) {"charset":"utf-16"}
09:35:19,511 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ==========================================
09:35:19,511 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) ======
09:35:19,526 INFO  [com.octavianlab.orgs.api] (default task-15) [1623317719509][Request] {
"id": "TESTSYMBOL",
"valuePrecision": 2,
"symbol": "???",
"plainascii": "&euro",
"unicode": "\u20AC",
"currencyConfig": "{\"id\": \"EUR\",\"Symbol\": \"???\", \"coinTo\": 0.02, \"useCents\": true, 
\"isSignFirst\": true, \"decimalSeparator\": \",\", \"currencyPrecision\": 2, \"registerSeparator\": \".\"}"
| }
```

and this is the request sent by postman

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: _"but i rly want to know where javax.ws.rs perform the conversion from bytestream into string (and then into pojo): "_ - This is done by [entity providers](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). It will depend on which one you're using. If you're using Jackson, then it will be the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.